# Vectorized-oriented definition of functions (Python)

Tags: python, vectorization, numerical-integration

I want to integrate a function using [quadpy](https://pypi.org/project/quadpy/). I noticed that quadpy passes numpy arrays as arguments to the function. For example, if I define `f = lambda x: x**2`, then quadpy will integrate passing a vector like `x = [0, 0.3, 0.7, 1]`.

The function I want to integrate is long (300 lines of code) and when I coded it I was thinking in passing two real numbers as arguments, not vectors. Now that I want to integrate or plot, it seems very important that my function can handle vectors. Which methods or tricks do you know to vectorize a function? numpy.vectorize does not seem to work in every case.

In my case, one of the problems is:

```
def f(t):
   U = np.array([[1, 0,          0        ],
                 [0, np.cos(t),  np.sin(t)],
                 [0, -np.sin(t), np.cos(t)]])
   V = np.array([[np.cos(t),  0,  np.sin(t)],
                 [0,          1,  0        ],
                 [-np.sin(t), 0, np.cos(t)]])

   return U @ V
```

When I run the code, quadpy replaces, say, `np.cos(t)` by an array, so the system throws an error telling me that I should specify 'dtype=object', and then the program collapses when it tries to operate `U @ V` over vectors.

How can I deal with these kind of problems? Other problem is that I multiply, say, `constant(t)*vector(l)`,
so the constant becomes a vector, *vector(l)* becomes an array of arrays, and the system starts to complain again. Should I always define my functions bearing vectorization in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check https://github.com/sigma-py/quadpy/wiki/Dimensionality-of-input-and-output-arrays on what the dimensions of the input array mean, and how to construct an output array.

Answer (score 1):

I want to show how I vectorized the function I posted. I refactored it as:

```
def f(t):
   ones = np.ones(t.shape)
   U = np.array([[ones,   0*ones,     0*ones   ],
                 [0*ones, np.cos(t),  np.sin(t)],
                 [0*ones, -np.sin(t), np.cos(t)]])
   V = np.array([[np.cos(t),  0*ones, np.sin(t)],
                 [0*ones,     ones,   0*ones   ],
                 [-np.sin(t), 0,      np.cos(t)]])
   U_theta = np.moveaxis(U_theta, [0, 1], [-2, -1])
   V_phi = np.moveaxis(V_phi, [0, 1], [-2, -1])

   return U @ V
```